# How to remove auto include feature

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to write C# code in Windows, and after a recent reinstall I noticed that now if I type a command which is included in another namespace of my project, VSC will proceed to autoinclude that namespace. I would like to know how to deactivate this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck `C# > Dotnet > Completion: Show Completion Items From UnimportedNamespaces` or add `"dotnet.completion.showCompletionItemsFromUnimportedNamespaces": false` to the settings.json